# Comments edited regarding safety?

Tags: discussion, moderation, comments

In, [DC-DC boost converter theory / principle / testing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/627710/dc-dc-boost-converter-theory-principle-testing#comment1659931_627710), I had a comment about something OP mentioned that I found concerning, regarding operating with a live battery; at least, I *think* I did?!  But without an edit history it seems it's as much hearsay, as gaslighting myself at this point.

If this was moderated, could a moderator indicate why this action was taken?

On a related note, I suppose the conversation never should've gone so far anyway, closed for poor focus; is that a fair assessment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If this was moderated, could a moderator indicate why this action was taken?

I've checked your comments on that question. As of now, no comments on that topic (by anyone) were deleted, by a moderator or by its author. A few were edited by their authors, within the usual 5-minute window. That's all!

> closed for poor focus

The question has never been closed. Perhaps you are thinking of a different question? Or a different site? That would explain why you can't find a comment here that you believe you wrote. That seems a likely explanation, and the exact same situation has happened to me.

Comment: Nah I mean, that it lacks focus so we maybe shouldn't have kept the thread going so long. Or put another way: vibe check, kinda. Anyway, thanks for checking!